# Isometric, draw only on screen tiles

Tags: c#, xna, drawing, isometric, tiles-game

I need to draw only the tiles on screen to increase performance. What is a viable way to do this?

I tried this that brings me close but end up with a bug i cant seem to solve.

```
//world position to start drawing from
        int sPosX = (int)(cam.Position.X - (device.Viewport.Width / 2));
        int sPosY = (int)(cam.Position.Y - (device.Viewport.Height / 2));

        //tile position to start drawing from
        int sTileX = (int)((sPosX + (2*sPosY) - (Map.TileWidth/2)) / Map.TileWidth -1);
        int sTileY = (int)((sPosX - (2 * sPosY) - (Map.TileHeight / 2)) / -Map.TileWidth - 1);

        //amount of rows/collumns to draw
        int rowCount = (int)(device.Viewport.Height / (Map.TileHeight / 2) + 2);
        int colCount = (int)(device.Viewport.Width / Map.TileWidth + 2);

        //current tile to draw
        int tileX;
        int tileY;


        for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < colCount; col++)
            {
                tileX = sTileX + col + (int)((row / 2));
                tileY = sTileY - col + (int)((row / 2));
                if (tileX >= 0 && tileX < tileMap.GetLength(0) && tileY >= 0 && tileY < tileMap.GetLength(1))
                {
                    batch.Draw(grid, new Rectangle((tileX * (TileWidth / 2)) - (tileY * (TileWidth / 2)), (tileX * (TileHeight / 2) + (tileY * (TileHeight / 2))), TileWidth, TileHeight), Color.White);
                    batch.DrawString(tiny, tileX + "," + tileY, new Vector2(tileX * (TileWidth / 2) - (tileY * (TileWidth / 2)) + 24, tileX * (TileHeight / 2) + (tileY * (TileHeight / 2)) + 12), Color.White);
                }
            }
        }
```

Here i try drawing my tilemap row by row. First i find out what the first tile to be drawn is (upper left corner) then i find out how many collumns and how many rows need to be drawn.

At first i only worked with floats and cast to end at the last moment, while converting the floats step by step to int i was able to get the full X=0 and full Y=0 row on the screen but the rest still showed up as this picture.

[image: Isometric display problem]

While moving the camera, the tiles shown/rendered switch between uneven and even, so if i move a small amount down suddenly all the tiles show in the picture disappear and the blanks get shown. Moving further and it reverses, if i keep moving it flickers between those two states. I figured it has something to do with the (row/2) but i cant seem to fix it.

The way i am calculating which tiles to draw seems to be good. I get this when i zoom out (zooming is not altering the formula yet). In the picture below you can see the 2nd state as well where the other tiles being drawn.

[image]

Comment: Obviously i have the answer not even half hour after i post this. The for loop draws each 1st or 2nd row double as is. I need to add "+(row%2)" to the tileX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tileX = sTileX + col + (int)((row / 2) + (row%2));
```

The modulus fixes it since on each second row should be increased by one in addition to the first.

Still i think this is valuable information as i spent hours finding out how to do this properly and ended up doing it myself. I think this is the most efficient way to draw everything since it allows for rendering a diamond style isometric map as a zigzag square.